# How to define default taxonomy for a page type in Grav CMS?

Tags: grav

In my current Grav project, I am trying to display the newest 5 posts of a specific type. For the purposes of this question, let's just call the post type 'book.'

I'm aware that this would be much easier if I simply made a page called "Books" and made every 'book' a child of that page, but the individual who will be using this website isn't particularly computer literate and is already finding the admin plugin interface daunting. I imagine there could be multiple instances where they would create a 'book' post and forget to assign it as a child of "Books."

So as a result, I decided that I would just set a default tag for the 'book' pages and use that taxonomy to create a page collection that I could just iterate over, that way, regardless of where the page is put, it will still be in the collection.

The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to set a default value for the taxonomy field type in the admin plugin.

I have attempted the following in my book.yaml file:

```
header.taxonomy:
  type: taxonomy
  label: PLUGIN_ADMIN.TAXONOMY
  multiple: true
  default:
    tag:
      - Book
  validate:
    type: array

header.taxonomy:
  type: taxonomy
  label: PLUGIN_ADMIN.TAXONOMY
  multiple: true
  default:
    - tag:
      - Book
  validate:
    type: array

header.taxonomy:
  type: taxonomy
  label: PLUGIN_ADMIN.TAXONOMY
  multiple: true
  default: {tag: [Book]}
  validate:
    type: array
```

I'm not sure what to do in this case, as the existing documentation doesn't seem to offer much in the way of help. Am I putting the default in the wrong place? Am I defining it in the wrong way? Is what I want to do even possible?

Answer (score 4):

I have managed to find the solution to my own dilemma.

```
header.taxonomy.tag:
  type: selectize
  label: Tag
  classes: fancy 
  default: Book
  validate:
    type: commalist
```

I'm not sure why this is the case, but this does not work without 'classes: fancy'

Comment: Did you unset `header.taxonomy: unset@: true` ?